# How to integrate this inline function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to integrate this function in terms of dx in matlab. Is there a function to do it?

```
f = inline('(k/l)*((x/l)^k-1)*(exp(-1*((x/l)^k)))','x','l','k');
```

Comment: Are you trying to do numeric quadrature or do you want an algebraic result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inline` function is depreciated. You should instead use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Assuming `k` and `l` are constants:

```
f = @(x) (k/l)*((x/l).^k-1).*(exp(-1*((x/l).^k)));
```

From there, there are any number of available [numerical integration functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numerical-integration-and-differentiation.html). I would start with `integral` and then work my way down.

```
value = integral(@f,a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26345824), it should be

```
value = integral(f,a,b);
```

instead of `value = integral(@f,a,b);`